# Xamarin: Assets path to load database from (shared project)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a cross-platform solution (iOS and Android), which has a common shared project, from which I try to load a database file.

I tried retrieving the folder path like so:

```
`Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); `

Path = System.IO.Path.Combine (Path, "database.db");
```

But the file does not exist in the resulting path.

I drag drop the database file into the iOS project, as well as the shared project, but it does not seem to work.

In iOS, the same operation could be accomplished using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"database" ofType:"db"]
```

How do I do that for a shared class, if it is possible?

Comment: I'm using Shared projects instead, as it better suits my requirements. Is there a way to achieve the functionality in Shared projects instead?

Answer (score 1):

"Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);" is not getting your app resources at all.
If you need the user to modify data you should copy your database (within your app resources) to that folder (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)) and that would be the file to open on the SQLite connection. From that point, the db file on your resources folder will no longer be useful, as it is not allowed to modify your app files.

> Note that you just need to copy the file once: ie the first time your app runs

That said, to use your db file (or other files) in your project you could add a reference to that file (as a link) and load it as you would load any asset from each particular platform.

See these links for more info on how to load assets:

ios: 
http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/file_system/load_a_file/

android: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/