# Read text file with PCLStorage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way to read an embedded JSON file in a PCL project with PCLStorage module? I looked everywhere but couldn't find a sample related to this matter.

EDIT: PCLStorage link: https://github.com/dsplaisted/pclstorage

Comment: Add link to the PCLStorage module

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29792738/5064986

Answer (score 4):

you need something like this:

```
public static async Task<string> ReadFileContent(string fileName, IFolder rootFolder)
{
  ExistenceCheckResult exist = await rootFolder.CheckExistsAsync(fileName);

  string text = null;
  if (exist == ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists)
  {
    IFile file = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    text = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
  }

  return text;
}
```

to use:

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
IFolder myCoolFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MyCoolForler", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
string fileContent = await this.ReadFileContent("MyCoolFile.txt", myCoolFolder);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know where the root folder is. The file is embedded into the assembly.

Comment: IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage; 
And you will have root folder, depending from platform

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to read embedded resources like this:

```
var assembly = typeof(LoadResourceText).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream)) {
    text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Xamarin has a great guide on how to work with them here.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Comment: Are you sure that you can use System.IO in a PCL project?